# how to remove reduce/reduce conflicts

Tags: bison, yacc

I am trying to solve few yacc problems.And in few of my tries goes in vain after getting conflicts: reduce/reduce error. FOr an example, i am trying to solve "string which accpets more 0's than 1's" and I write this following code which shows reduce/reduce conflict(I am giving only the rules section here):

```
    s   :   s1 ';'   {printf("valid");exit(0);}
        ;
    s1  :   '0' '1' '0' s   
        |   '0' '0' '1' s
        |   '1' '0' '0' s
        |   '0' s
        | 
        ;
```

Can any one tell me what i have made wrong here I will appreciate if u advice me in future how to I get recovered from this error.

THank you,

Answer (score 1):

You're using right-recursion rather than left-recursion.  Generally, left-recursion is preferred in Bison and Yacc grammars.  It is also a bit odd that you have `s` rather than `s1` in the `s1` rules.

The verbose output file (`bison -v rrconf.y` yields `rrconf.output`) says:

```
State 20 conflicts: 1 reduce/reduce
State 21 conflicts: 1 reduce/reduce

Grammar

    0 $accept: s $end

    1 s: s1 ';'

    2 s1: '0' '1' '0' s
    3   | '0' '0' '1' s
    4   | '1' '0' '0' s
    5   | '0' s
    6   | /* empty */

...

state 20

    2 s1: '0' '1' '0' s .
    5   | '0' s .

    ';'       reduce using rule 2 (s1)
    ';'       [reduce using rule 5 (s1)]
    $default  reduce using rule 2 (s1)


state 21

    4 s1: '1' '0' '0' s .
    5   | '0' s .

    ';'       reduce using rule 4 (s1)
    ';'       [reduce using rule 5 (s1)]
    $default  reduce using rule 4 (s1)
```

It's easy to change the grammar to use left-recursion:

```
%%
s   :   s1 ';'   {printf("valid");exit(0);}
    ;
s1  : s1 '0' '1' '0'
    | s1 '0' '0' '1'
    | s1 '1' '0' '0'
    | s1 '0'
    | 
    ;
%%
```

It leaves you with two shift/reduce conflicts (which are much less serious than reduce/reduce conflicts):

```
State 5 conflicts: 2 shift/reduce

Grammar

    0 $accept: s $end

    1 s: s1 ';'

    2 s1: s1 '0' '1' '0'
    3   | s1 '0' '0' '1'
    4   | s1 '1' '0' '0'
    5   | s1 '0'
    6   | /* empty */

...


state 5

    2 s1: s1 '0' . '1' '0'
    3   | s1 '0' . '0' '1'
    5   | s1 '0' .

    '0'  shift, and go to state 7
    '1'  shift, and go to state 8

    '0'       [reduce using rule 5 (s1)]
    '1'       [reduce using rule 5 (s1)]
    $default  reduce using rule 5 (s1)
```

Whether that's sufficient for you, I'm not sure.

You still have another problem, though — a high-level algorithm design problem.  An input of 10 `1`'s followed by 11 `0`'s meets the requirement of more zeros than ones, but won't be recognized by this grammar.

Comment: Why are reduce/reduce conflicts less serious than shift/reduce?  They both mean the grammar is not LALR(1).  They both mean that the generated parser only accepts a subset of the language described by the grammar.  They both mean that you need to use a different grammar if you want yacc to accept the language.  In any case, none of these grammars match the language described.